# How to style diagonal backgrounds with Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

How to create diagonal styled backgrounds (like in the screenshot below) when using Bootstrap 5 and (s)css?

Ideally working nicely together with the other Bootstrap background utilities documented here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/background/

So e.g. when having:

```
<div class="bg-primary-subtle text-emphasis-primary">
  Lorem ipsum.
</div>
```

or with other color and gradient and opacity:

```
<div class="bg-success text-white bg-gradient bg-opacity-75">
  Lorem ipsum.
</div>
```

to be able to easily add the diagonal effect (in either direction up/down)?

[image]

or sometimes:

[image]

Comment: Use custom CSS and `clip-path` or pseudo-elements

Comment: This isn’t something Bootstrap would handle or has utilities out of the box for achieving. At some point you have to write custom CSS to implement your designs.

Comment: You can have two adjacent divs whose backgrounds need to blend together?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `clip-path` to cut the top side:

```css
:root {
  --offset: 1.5em;
}

.diagonal-grid > div:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: calc(var(--offset) * -1); 
}

.diagonal-grid > div:nth-child(even) {
  clip-path: polygon(0 var(--offset), 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.diagonal-grid > div:not(:first-child):nth-child(odd) {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% var(--offset), 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<section class="diagonal-grid">
  <div class="bg-primary-subtle text-emphasis-primary p-5">
    Lorem ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="bg-danger-subtle text-emphasis-primary p-5">
    Lorem ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="bg-info text-emphasis-primary p-5">
    Lorem ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="bg-body-tertiary text-emphasis-primary p-5">
    Lorem ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="bg-success text-emphasis-primary p-5">
    Lorem ipsum.
  </div>
</section>
```

If you want to write in SCSS you can use something like this:

```scss
.diagonal-grid {
  $offset: 1.5em;
  
  > div {
    &:nth-child(even) {
      clip-path: polygon(0 $offset, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    }
    &:not(:first-child) {
      margin-top: calc(#{$offset} * -1);
      &:nth-chil(odd) {
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% var(--offset), 100% 100%, 0 100%);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can also add classes dynamically to specify which corner you want to cut. Note though, that cutting away the top side of an element does not work as intended. You should only use it to cut way the top of the first element.

```css
:root {
  --offset: 1.5em;
}

.diagonal-grid > .cut-top-left {
  clip-path: polygon(0 var(--offset), 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.diagonal-grid > .cut-top-right {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% var(--offset), 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.diagonal-grid > .cut-bottom-left {
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--offset) * -1);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 calc(100% - var(--offset)));
}

.diagonal-grid > .cut-bottom-right {
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--offset) * -1);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - var(--offset)), 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<section style="height:5vh; background-color: gray;"><section>
<section class="diagonal-grid">
  <div class="bg-primary-subtle text-emphasis-primary p-5 cut-top-left">
    Lorem ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="bg-danger-subtle text-emphasis-primary p-5 cut-bottom-left">
    Lorem ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="bg-info text-emphasis-primary p-5 cut-bottom-right">
    Lorem ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="bg-body-tertiary text-emphasis-primary p-5">
    Lorem ipsum.
  </div>
</section>
```

```scss
.diagonal-grid {
  $offset: 1.5em;

  > .cut-
    &top- {
      &left {
        clip-path: polygon(0 var(--offset), 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
      }
      &right {
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% var(--offset), 100% 100%, 0 100%);
      }
    
    &bottom- {
      margin-bottom: calc(var(--offset) * -1);
      &left {
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 calc(100% - var(--offset)));
      }
      &right {
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - var(--offset)), 0 100%);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx @tacoshy, I've updated the questions a bit, with a second screenshot. I wonder if it can be implemented in a more granular way, so that per <div> I can choose whether to display a diagonal at the top and/or bottom and which direction (up or down)?

Comment: ok I will edit the answer later on to take that into account

Comment: thx, looking forward to the update.

Comment: you want to update the answer so I can accept it as the answer?